# How to categorize list of dictionaries based on the value of a key in python efficiently?

Tags: python, list, categorization

I have a list of dictionaries in python which I want to categorized them based on the value of a key which exists in all dictionaries and process each category separately. I don't know what are the values, I just know that there exists a special key. Here's the list:

```
dictList = [
            {'name': 'name1', 'type': 'type1', 'id': '14464'}, 
            {'name': 'name2', 'type': 'type1', 'id': '26464'},
            {'name': 'name3', 'type': 'type3', 'id': '36464'},
            {'name': 'name4', 'type': 'type5', 'id': '43464'},
            {'name': 'name5', 'type': 'type2', 'id': '68885'}
            ]
```

This is the code I currently use:

```
while len(dictList):
    category = [l for l in dictList if l['type'] == dictList[0]['type']]
    processingMethod(category)
    for item in category:
        dictList.remove(item)
```

This iteration on the above list will give me following result:

```
Iteration 1:
            category = [
                        {'name': 'name1', 'type': 'type1', 'id': '14464'}, 
                        {'name': 'name2', 'type': 'type1', 'id': '26464'},
                        ]

Iteration 2:
            category = [
                        {'name': 'name3', 'type': 'type3', 'id': '36464'}
                        ]

Iteration 3:
            category = [
                        {'name': 'name4', 'type': 'type5', 'id': '43464'}
                        ]

Iteration 4:
            category = [
                        {'name': 'name5', 'type': 'type2', 'id': '68885'}
                        ]
```

Each time, I get a category, process it and finally remove processed items to iterate over remaining items, until there is no remaining item. Any idea to make it better?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code can be rewritten using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
for _, category in itertools.groupby(dictList, key=lambda item:item['type']):
    processingMethod(list(category))
```

Or if processingMethod can process `iterable`,

```
for _, category in itertools.groupby(dictList, key=lambda item:item['type']):
    processingMethod(category)
```

Comment: I didn't know this existed! This is much nicer than my solution.

Comment: Your answer seems really fantastic, I'll try it and let you know about the results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mskimm. It completely fits my problem.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi I'd just like to add the caveat that the groups all have to be together; that is, you can't have an element of type 1, then an element type 2, then another element of type 1. Instead, all the elements of type 1 have to be together in the original list. If they aren't guaranteed to be together, it's necessary to run `dictList.sort(key=lambda item: item['type'])` first.

Answer (score 1):

If `l['type']` is hashable for each `l` in `dictList`, here's a possible, somewhat-elegant solution:

```
bins = {}

for l in dictList:
    if l['type'] in bins:
        bins[l['type']].append(l)
    else:
        bins[l['type']] = [l]

for category in bins.itervalues():
   processingMethod(category)
```

The idea is that first, we'll sort all the `l`s into bins, using `l['type']` as the key; second, we'll process each bin.

If `l['type']` isn't guaranteed to be hashable for each `l` in `dictList`, the approach is essentially the same, but we'll have to use a list of tuples instead of the dict, which means this is a bit less efficient:

```
bins = []

for l in dictList:
    for bin in bins:
        if bin[0] == l['type']:
            bin[1].append(l)
            break
    else:
        bins.append((l['type'], [l]))

for _, category in bins:
   processingMethod(category)
```